# 13.04 Won't boot after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.04

I have a laptop with a dual-boot configuration, Windows 7 in one partition, Ubuntu 13.04 on the other. It was working fine for months, but now, after one of Ubuntu's recommended updates, it won't work anymore.
When I boot into Windows, everything works fine, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu, the screen stays black with just a blinking white underscore as if it was a command prompt. (It won't accept any typing, though). Can anyone help?

I saw some solutions that mention Grub, but I don't know how to access that, or even if I have that. When I turn on the computer, I have a menu similar to this one:

[image]

But instead of Microsoft Windows Vista, the options are "Windows 7" and "Ubuntu". If I choose Ubuntu, I'm stuck on a black screen with a blinking prompt.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?  Did you use a Windows Installer called WUBI?

Comment: @brim4brim  WUBI is not available in 13.04.

Comment: I had Ubuntu Installed as 12.10 and upgraded it. I used Universal USB Installer (This: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) with a Ubuntu ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Try recovery mode.  To boot into recovery mode, just press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, which will bring up a boot menu.  Choose (recovery mode).  See if this fixes your issue.

For more information on what can be done in recovery mode, see [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

[image]

Comment: Following your instructions, the only thing that happened when I pressed shift was that instead of having a black screen with a blinking prompt, I now have a black screen, with "GRUB" written on it and a blinking prompt...

Comment: There is a way to properly recover it by editing the windows file but I don't know if it would work in 13.04 but I think you could configure grub to work too.  However you'll have to wait for someone with the expertise to come along